# nothing happens when running "python manage.py sql polls"

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am trying to get Django running on Google App Engine using Django non-rel. I am following the [Django 1.5 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) However, when i run:

```
python manage.py sql polls
```

nothing is returned. **Can anyone suggest why 'manage.py sql' is silently failing?**

When I sync the database I get:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

The database is specified in settings.py as follows:

```
# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': DATABASES['default']}
AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'
```

and I have remembered to include 'polls' in the settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
#    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    'polls',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)
```

and the models are present in polls/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

NOTE: If I change settings.py to use a local sqlite3 database, 'manage.py sql polls' behaves as described in the tutorial. Therefore, as far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with:

1. the /polls directory structure
2. the /polls/models.py file
3. the python path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect it do anything? GAE is, specifically, a non-relational (NoSQL) datastore. There is quite simply no SQL to produce.

You should be aware that GAE, even with django-non-rel, is quite different from standard Django, and following the Django tutorial is only likely to confuse you.

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting 'manage.py sql polls' to return the equivalent SQL. I though this as I viewed the db back end to be separate from Django; and polls/models.py had not changed. Unfortunately the Django-norel documentation is quite poor. Would you have any recommended guides for getting  Django-norel setup on Google-App-Engine? (Thank you in advance, I'm still very new to Django).

Comment: Look at the documentation and instalation instructions at http://django-nonrel.org/. Try django-testapp from django-nonrel project https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-testapp its a great start for learning django nonrel.